# Are there any tools to handle spell check in the Silverlight RichTextBox?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox, spell-checking

I am looking for any tool or good solution for handling spell check in the RichTextBox for Silverlight 4. Does anyone know of an existing solution or a good way to implement spell checking support for this control?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this Free [Rich Text Editor](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls/rich_text_editor.aspx) from Vectorlight.  Includes a spell checker.

Comment: Can its contents be obtained as XAML?

Comment: @benrick: thats a good question.  I know that in the past Vectorlight were experimenting with a SL4 RichTextBox based solution.  Whether that is what is actually being used in the final SL4 solution I don't know and/or whether it exposes the Xaml property.  Download it and have a look.  Also worth asking is, does it need to?

Answer (score 0):

Developers Express are releasing a Spell Checker that works with the Silverlight RichTextBox. It has just been released in beta for version 2011.1, the final release should be in a few weeks time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best route is a third-party component. For example, Telerik's [RadRichTextBox](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/MSWord) supports spell checking with experience similar to the RichTextBox from WPF - with underlines for incorrect words, context menu with suggestions, custom dictionaries,  and so on. There is also spell checking dialog similar to the one found in Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0):

[SpellLight](https://spelllight.codeplex.com/) is a lightweight library which will let you do the spell checks against Google APIs.